# Using Mutate and conditional statement to calculate column means

Tags: r

I have a dataset with an identifier variable and some numeric variables. I want to calculate the mean of the columns according to the identifier variable. Here is a simple example:

From this

```
id v1 v2 v3 v4
 d  1  2 NA NA
 e  NA NA 3  3
 e  NA NA 2  4
 d  3  5 NA NA
```

I want to get to this:

```
 id v1 v2 v3 v4 mean
 d  1  2  NA NA 1.5
 e  NA NA  3  3 3
 e  NA NA  2  4 3
 d  3  5  NA NA 4
```

I would like to use an if else statement like:

```
ifelse(id=d, colMeans(v1:v2), colMeans(v3:v4)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would use an 'apply' function.

Comment: You say you want to compute the mean "according to the identifier variable," but it’s not really clear from your example how you want the id variable to figure in. You’ll probably want to use the answer linked by @Maël along with `if_else()` or `case_when()`, but hard to say without more info.

Comment: Yes that would be a solution. But I could not figure out how to do it. I specified my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(c_across(v1:v4), na.rm = T))

# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Rowwise: 
  id       v1    v2    v3    v4  mean
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1 d         1     2    NA    NA   1.5
2 e        NA    NA     3     3   3  
3 e        NA    NA     2     4   3  
4 d         3     5    NA    NA   4
```

Or:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(c_across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = T))
```